# pyspark equivalent code for panda's evm (Exponential moving average)

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to calculate the EVM (Exponential moving average) of units, I am using pandas `evm` method like

```
tup = [
    (3634, "2022-11-12","3.26"), (3634, "2022-11-13","2.97"),(3634, "2022-11-14","5.3"),
    (3634, "2022-11-15","11.94"),(3634, "2022-11-16","5.5"),(3634, "2022-11-17","11.02")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(tup, ["id", "date","units"])
df.show()

+----+----------+-----+
|  id|      date|units|
+----+----------+-----+
|3634|2022-11-12| 3.26|
|3634|2022-11-13| 2.97|
|3634|2022-11-14|  5.3|
|3634|2022-11-15|11.94|
|3634|2022-11-16|  5.5|
|3634|2022-11-17|11.02|
+----+----------+-----+
```

In pandas:

```
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
pandas_df["ewm"] = pandas_df["units"].ewm(alpha=0.7, min_periods=0).mean()
spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df).show() 

+----+----------+-----+-----------------+
|  id|      date|units|              ewm|
+----+----------+-----+-----------------+
|3634|2022-11-12| 3.26|             3.26|
|3634|2022-11-13| 2.97|3.036923076923077|
|3634|2022-11-14|  5.3|4.665035971223021|
|3634|2022-11-15|11.94| 9.79909668313338|
|3634|2022-11-16|  5.5|6.782398428180479|
|3634|2022-11-17|11.02|9.750883554110947|
+----+----------+-----+-----------------+
```

I wanted to know if i could do the same in pyspark without using `pandas_udf`. Preferable ably with Windows function.

Any lead is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: EMA's computation is recursive and serial. Spark's distributed architecture is not efficient for such computations. There are lots similar questions on this forum, and the acquiesced approach seems to using pandas_udf.